# Why is Nmap traceroute so fast?

Tags: networking, traceroute, nmap

Using Nmap's traceroute option shows only one hop and is extremely fast.  I understand it works differently than traceroute in that it tries to guess the right TTL instead of beginning with 1.  But why is the RTT so fast?  I have repeated this 10 times and the RTT is always in the range of 0.02 - 0.03 ms.

```
# nmap -Pn -T4 --traceroute xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-06-25 12:25 PDT
Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
Not shown: 991 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
<redacted>    

TRACEROUTE (using port 113/tcp)
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   0.03 ms xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.74 seconds
```

Using standard `traceroute -T` shows 8 hops.  Repeating this 10 times shows a final RTT range between 0.77 - 1.20 ms.  Both servers are on fast dedicated internet within 10 miles of each other, but 0.03 ms RTT seems unrealistic considering router processing time.

Comment: What `traceroute` command did you try? Compare both side-by-side. Also try 10-20 times and average them.

Comment: I used `traceroute -T` followed by the IP address.  I added repeatability results to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your logs show that Nmap's traceroute works by sending TCP probes to port 113 (ident service). My guess is that your server's firewall, for some reason, blocks outgoing connections to that port – and it does so by faking a TCP RST, which Nmap interprets as a regular response to the probe. (Because it would indeed have received a TCP RST from the final hop, in most cases.)

Compare with `traceroute --tcp=113`.

Rejecting incoming Ident connections is normal. Doing the same for outgoing connections, however, is almost always completely useless. (Cargo-culting firewall rules?)